# how can I display MFMessageComposeViewController in the main window?

Tags: ios, animation, user-interface, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have two navigation controllers that are nested together, the first nav is in the front and the other one is in the background. So to view the other view I have sliding animation like facebook app.

But my problem is when I call to show message UI on the second navigation view its just show me black window. It may have affect of the first view thats infront of it.

So my question is how to display the message UI to main window?
this might solve the problem rather than showing to one of the navigation views.

Comment: You need to better explain how your two naviagion controllers are situated in the window. Do you use a container viewController, or a UIPageController?

Comment: The root view controller is a navigation controller(with viewcontroller) and in that navigation view I add subviews, two navigation controller view with a view controllers as their roots views(the one is behind the other, the purpose is so i can push weather im on the other view). So when the app load the first will I see is the navigation controller view that on top of all added to subviews. then I have a button that will slide the top view to see the view behind(like facebook).